# Excel big database

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a really large database and I have to see which numbers appear most often. I know about the `MODE` function, but while it gives me the most common number, I would like it to list the top 5 or 10. All numbers are not one below other.

I'm also having problems because my numbers are not perfectly entered, its like this:
[image]

Comment: Excel isn't a database! Also, what is your question? And what have you tried?

Comment: please clarify what kind of numbers you have: the first cell doesn't hold a number but a string (with spaces).

Comment: While I agree with @Dave, in that excel is not a database, short of building a new one, a Pivot Table may be able to help. Select your column of numbers, then the count of those numbers.

Comment: You can use **Text to columns** under **Data** to break the column down so each cell has 1 value.

Comment: The first and last cell in  your current images are not a numbers or a group of numbers as far as excel is concerned, it's a text (but for humans it reads as numbers). I also agree with Dave; Excel is not a database, that would be Access. If you were to format your data and then merge it into Acess Database, then you could easily perform the task via queries and there is a top-10 query built in.